# bootstrap-typeahead search indexs my own site

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, typeahead, twitter-typeahead

Im not really sure how to go to the new page the user is searching for in my site. For example when somebody search for "Maths Leaving Cert" I want them to be redirected to the Maths.html page Could anyone help me out please?

Heres my code:

```
 <div id="the-basics" class="form-group">
    <input id="subjects-input" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
</div>

    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "../jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../bootstrap-typeahead.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
$('#subjects-input').typeahead({
    source: [
    {name: 'Accounting | Leaving Cert' },
    {name: 'Applied Maths | Leaving Cert' },
    {name: 'Art | Leaving Cert' },
    {name: 'Biology | Leaving Cert' },
    {name: 'Business | Leaving Cert' },
    {name: 'Chemistry | Leaving Cert' },
    {name: 'Classical Studies | Leaving Cert' },
    {name: 'Construction Studies | Leaving Cert' },
    {name: 'DCG | Leaving Cert' },
    {name: 'Economics | Leaving Cert' },
    {name: 'Engineering | Leaving Cert' },
    {name: 'English | Leaving Cert' },
    {name: 'French | Leaving Cert' },
    {name: 'Geography| Leaving Cert' },
    {name: 'German | Leaving Cert' },
    {name: 'History | Leaving Cert' },
    {name: 'Home Economics | Leaving Cert' },
    {name: 'Irish | Leaving Cert' },
    {name: 'Italian | Leaving Cert' },
    {name: 'Latin| Leaving Cert' },
    {name: 'Mathematics | Leaving Cert' },
    {name: 'Music | Leaving Cert' },
    {name: 'Physisc | Leaving Cert' },
    {name: 'Religious Education| Leaving Cert' },
    {name: 'Art | Junior Cert' },
    {name: 'Business | Junior Cert' },
    {name: 'Classical Studies | Junior Cert' },
    {name: 'CSPE | Junior Cert' },
    {name: 'English | Junior Cert' },
    {name: 'French | Junior Cert' },
    {name: 'Geography | Junior Cert' },
    {name: 'German | Junior Cert' },
    {name: 'History | Junior Cert' },
    {name: 'Home Economics| Junior Cert' },
    {name: 'Irish | Junior Cert' },
    {name: 'Italian | Junior Cert' },
    {name: 'Mathematics | Junior Cert' },
    {name: 'Music | Junior Cert' },
    {name: 'Religious Education| Junior Cert' },
    {name: 'Science | Junior Cert' },
    {name: 'Spanish| Junior Cert' },
    {name: 'Technical Graphics| Junior Cert' },
    {name: 'Material Technology (Woodwork) | Junior Cert' }

    ]
});

</script>
```

Comment: What you're showing here simply addresses the issue of surfacing search results.  You would need a way to convert what the user ultimately selects into a redirect to the appropriate page.  That's not something that can be explained in a few sentences.  Please make an attempt to learn the subject matter first.  Then, if you still have problems, come back to this forum for specific assistance.  Thank you.

Comment: @EricTaylor Ok thanks for the advice, do you know of any good tutorials or examples I could look at?

Comment: Not specifically, no.  I only know how I would approach the problem.  But at this point, I wouldn't want to take the joy out of your journey.  Once you've wrestled with it, post what you have accomplished, and then we can discuss what you have and where to go from there.